# Trying to have table row get highlighted once a checkbox in the same row gets checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I apologize in advance for being messy or unclear. It is my first time posting question on a forum regarding coding issue as I am very new at this... I am trying to have the whole table row get highlighted in any color once the checkbox in the  gets checked while getting rid of the readonly attribute of other elements in specific row.

```
<div class="content">
<table style="width: 85%" class="itemTable">
<tr class="itemDesc">
<td></td>
<td>Item Description</td>
<td>Item Number</td>
<td>Box Amount</td>
<td>Individual Amount</td>
<td>Price</td>
<td>Special</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="item-check"></td>
<td>Black Bean(inside yellow)</td>
<td>20021</td>
<td><input type="numbers" class="box-amount" readonly></td>
<td><input type="numbers" class="each-amount" size="6" readonly></td>
<td><input type="numbers" class="price"size="6" readonly></td>
<td><input type="numbers" class="special" size="6" readonly></td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

this is part of the table I have. Thank you.

Comment: use jQuery or javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one without `jQuery`:

```js
function checkChanged(){
 var ar=event.target.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("input");
 if(event.target.checked)
    {
  /*event.target.parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor="rgba(213,113,18,0.4)";*/
      event.target.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add("selected");
  for(var i=0;i<ar.length;i++){ar[i].removeAttribute("readonly");}
 }
 else
 {  /*event.target.parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor="rgba(255,255,255,1)";*/
      event.target.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove("selected");
  for(var i=0;i<ar.length;i++){ar[i].setAttribute("readonly",true);}
 }
}
```

```css
.selected{
    background-color:rgba(213,113,81,0.4);
  }
```

```html
<table style="width: 85%" class="itemTable">
        <tr class="itemDesc">
            <td></td>
            <td>Item Description</td>
            <td>Item Number</td>
            <td>Box Amount</td>
            <td>Individual Amount</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Special</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="item-check" onclick="checkChanged()"/>
            </td>
            <td>Black Bean(inside yellow)</td>
            <td>20021</td>
            <td>
                <input type="numbers" class="box-amount" readonly/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="numbers" class="each-amount" size="6" readonly/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="numbers" class="price" size="6" readonly/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="numbers" class="special" size="6" readonly/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="item-check" onclick="checkChanged(this)"/>
            </td>
            <td>Black Bean(inside red)</td>
            <td>20022</td>
            <td>
                <input type="numbers" class="box-amount" readonly/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="numbers" class="each-amount" size="6" readonly/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="numbers" class="price" size="6" readonly/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="numbers" class="special" size="6" readonly/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/aqm7kjbg/9/

```
$("table tr").click(function(){

   var a = $(this).find('td input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked');
    if(a === true){
         $('.itemTable tr:nth-child('+ (this.rowIndex + 1) + ')').attr('style', 'background-color:red');;
    }else{
          $('.itemTable tr:nth-child('+ (this.rowIndex + 1) + ')').removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```

Comment: well it breaks if there are more than 2 rows !

Comment: well try using `parents("tr")` or `parent().parent()` to get the `tr`

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".itemTable input:checkbox").click(function() {
$(this).parent().parent().toggleClass("highlight")
})
})
</script>
<style>
.highlight {
background-color:#c9c9c9;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table style="width: 85%" class="itemTable">
<tr class="itemDesc">
<td> </td>
<td>Item Description</td>
<td>Item Number</td>
<td>Box Amount</td>
<td>Individual Amount</td>
<td>Price</td>
<td>Special</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="select" value="#artid#"></td>
<td>Black Bean(inside yellow)</td>
<td>20021</td>
<td><input type="numbers" class="box-amount" readonly></td>
<td><input type="numbers" class="each-amount" size="6" readonly></td>
<td><input type="numbers" class="price"size="6" readonly></td>
<td><input type="numbers" class="special" size="6" readonly></td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

source : http://www.raymondcamden.com/2009/11/18/jQuery-Quickie-Highlighting-a-table-row-after-selecting-a-checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a css class for highlighting the row and some basic jquery:

```js
$('.item-check').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    highlightRow($(this).parents("tr"));
    setRowEditable($(this).parents("tr"));
  } else {
    unhighlightRow($(this).parents("tr"));
    setRowUneditable($(this).parents("tr"));
  }
});

function highlightRow(row) {
  $(row).addClass("highlighted-row");
}

function unhighlightRow(row) {
  $(row).removeClass("highlighted-row");
}

function setRowEditable(row) {
  $(row).find(".box-amount, .each-amount, .price, .special").each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("readonly");
  });
}

function setRowUneditable(row) {
  $(row).find(".box-amount, .each-amount, .price, .special").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("readonly", "true");
  });
}
```

```css
.highlighted-row {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <table style="width: 85%" class="itemTable">
    <tr class="itemDesc">
      <td></td>
      <td>Item Description</td>
      <td>Item Number</td>
      <td>Box Amount</td>
      <td>Individual Amount</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Special</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="item-check" />
      </td>
      <td>Black Bean(inside yellow)</td>
      <td>20021</td>
      <td>
        <input type="numbers" class="box-amount" readonly />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="numbers" class="each-amount" size="6" readonly />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="numbers" class="price" size="6" readonly />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="numbers" class="special" size="6" readonly />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="item-check" />
      </td>
      <td>Black Bean(inside yellow)</td>
      <td>20021</td>
      <td>
        <input type="numbers" class="box-amount" readonly />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="numbers" class="each-amount" size="6" readonly />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="numbers" class="price" size="6" readonly />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="numbers" class="special" size="6" readonly />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```